# How to see that $PSU(2)$ is same as $SO(3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Some background:

We have an action of $SU(2)$ on the space of traceless Hermitian matrices, $\mathcal{H}$, via conjugation: $$SU(2)\times \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}, \ (U,H)\mapsto UHU^{-1}.$$
The ineffectivity, $I$ , of this action is $I=\{+Id, -Id\}$.

We define $PSU(2)$ as the quotient of $SU(2)$ over this ineffectivity i.e. $$PSU(2):= SU(2)/\{+Id, -Id\}$$

We thus have an effective action $$PSU(2)\times \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}, \ (UI, H)\mapsto UHU^{-1}.$$

Now, I want to show that $PSU(2)=SO(3).$ I am reading a file that says above effective action implies that we have $PSU(2)$ naturally as a subgroup of $SO(3)$. I don't understand this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the point is that $SO(3)$ is the group of linear transformation of a three-dimensional real vector space, preserving orientation and some fixed real inner product. So it would be enough to find that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group  "The group SU(2) is isomorphic to the group of quaternions of norm 1, and is thus diffeomorphic to the 3-sphere. Since unit quaternions can be used to represent rotations in 3-dimensional space (up to sign), there is a surjective homomorphism from SU(2) to the rotation group SO(3) whose kernel is {+I, −I}."

Comment: Are you just looking for an explanation of the embedding $f:PSU(2) \to SO(3)$ that the action you defined gives you, or the full proof that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: The main point that seems to be missing is a real inner product structure on the space of Hermitian matrices (or just those of trace$~0$) that is preserved under unitary conjugation. Once that is given, you can associate to the action of any $g\in SU(2)$ an element of $SO(3)$. Do you know about such an inner product structure, or is your question about finding one?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, I know a unitary structure: We can define $(A,B):=Tr(AB^*)$, where * denotes conjugate-transpose. This norm is $SU(2)$ invariant. Now, given this, how can I have what you said? I know that the orbits of $SU(2)$ are contained in spheres. If for instance, $||H||=r,$ then $SU(2).H$ agrees with the sphere of radius $r$. I would be happy to see a full answer from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You constructed an action $PSU(2) \to GL(H)$. Using the fact that $H$ is $3$-dimensional, it's easy to show that your map actually defines an action $\rho:PSU(2) \to SO(3)$. The fact that it's effective means that for any $g\not = g'$ in $PSU(2)$, there exists some $x\in H$ such that $\rho(g)x \not = \rho(g')x$; that is, the maps $\rho(g), \rho(g')\in SO(3)$ differ. That just means that the map $\rho:PSU(2)\to SO(3)$ is injective and thus gives an embedding of $PSU(2)$ as a subgroup of $SO(3)$.

(To complete the proof and show that that subgroup is actually $SO(3)$, there are a couple of ways to proceed: show explicitly that suitable generators of $SO(3)$ lie in the image, use some Lie group machinery, etc.)

Comment: I constructed an action $PSU(2) \times \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}.$ How does this imply your first statement? Also, I don't understand how $\rho$ is defined. After understanding this, I might be able to use some Lie group theory to show two groups are equal.

Comment: Given your action $f:PSU(2) \times H \to H$, the action is given by $\rho(g)x = f(g, x)$.

Comment: I know that both Lie groups are three dimensional and connected. What theorem(s) will help me conclude the proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let me be more explicit: suppose you have an element
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z & -\bar{w} \\
w & \bar{z}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
of $SU(2)$. Then $\|w\|^2 + \|z\|^2 = 1$. Writing $z = a + bi$ and $w = c + di$, you can form the vector $v = (b, c, d) / \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$ and the angle $\theta = \arccos(2a)$.

Rodrigues' formula, applied to the axis-angle pair $(v, \theta)$ gives an element of $R(v, \theta)$ of $SO(3)$. If you look at the formula, it's clear that $R(-v, -\theta) = R(v, \theta)$, so this mapping passes to the quotient, providing a mapping from $PSU(2)$ to $SO(3)$. It takes only a little work to show that it's 1-1, and you're done.